# ¿Cómo hacer que SweetAlert2 cancele el clic en un checkbox?

Tags: sweetalert2

Quiero remplazar los confirm de mi proyecto por diálogos de SweetAlert2 pero tengo un problema para manejar el cancel.
Quiero que al hacer clic en un checkbox muestre un dialogo de confirmación y que si el usuario hace clic en el botón de cancelar el checkbox no me quede seleccionado.

Mi código:

```
$(element).click(function (e) {
                            swal({
                                title: 'Seleccionado',
                                text: "¿Está seguro que desea seleccionarlo?",
                                type: 'warning',
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                                cancelButtonText: 'No'
                            }).then((result) => {
                                if (result.value) {
                                    guardar(true);
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                           });
                        });
```

Por algún motivo al hacer clic en "No" ejecuta lo que ponga en el else pero igual queda seleccionado el checkbox.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto el retornar `true | false` para cancelar la acción del usuario.

Sin embargo, cuando empleas javascript de forma asíncrona ( `swal({}).then((...)=>{})` ), debes tener en cuenta que el navegador está ejecutando tu manejador como una función regular `() => {}` no cómo un función asíncrona `async () => {}`.

Por lo que incluso, aún declarando el manejador como una función asíncrona, y utilizando la sintaxis `await`. El navegador no esperaría este comportamiento y no conseguirías retornar el valor deseado.

Para tratar de explicarlo mejor, te dejo un laboratorio con sintaxis **async / await** para la `Promise` de swal.

**Este fragmento es sólo un laboratorio**

En él podrás apreciar como el manejador asignado al evento retorna constantemente un valor positivo para una operación lógica, echando por tierra cualquier reacción del usuario por cancelar su acción.

```js
// fn guardar
guardar = () => {}

// async fn handler
handler = async function (e) {
  console.log('[Handler] Lanzamos swal, esperamos respuesta del usuario');
  console.log('[Handler]' + new Date());
 var r = await swal({
     title: 'Seleccionado',
     text: "¿Está seguro que desea seleccionarlo?",
     type: 'warning',
     showCancelButton: true,
     confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
     cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
     confirmButtonText: 'Si',
     cancelButtonText: 'No'
 });
  console.log('[Handler] ¡Gracias por la respuesta!');
  console.log(r);
  console.log('[Handler] ' + new Date());
  if (r.value) {
    guardar(true);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ejecutamos el manejador como una función regular
console.log('[Lab] Ejecutamos nuestro manejador como una función regular, de la misma forma que lo realizará el navegador');
console.log('[Lab] Nuestro manajador siempre retornará (exp) [' + (handler() ? 'true' : 'false') + '] si es llamada como una función regular. Y no podremos retornal el valor real');


// Lo mismo ocurre cuando es el navegador quien lo ejecuta a través de el evento 'click' de cualquier elemento
$('input[name="test"]').click( handler );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.28.4/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" />
```

**Una posible respuesta**

Por otro lado, existen distintas vías para lograr el funcionamiento propuesto.

En la siguiente solución mantendremos la sintaxis `swal({}).then(...){}` para lograr un funcionamiento asíncrono, realizando una doble verificación a través de la propiedad personalizada `data-sure`.

Nuestro manejador retornara `false` para evitar cambiar el estado de nuestro checkbox y mostrará el componente `swal` al usuario.

Cuando `swal` retorna la promesa resuelta, evaluaremos el resultado.

Con resultado afirmativo, marcaremos `data-sure` a `true` y volveremos a ejecutar el el manejador del evento 'click' de forma programática.

Si el `checkbox` contiene la propiedad personalizada `data-sure` o en su defecto ya fue 'marcado' por el usuario. Permitiremos la acción `return true`.

**Ver en funcionamiento**

```js
// fn guardar
guardar = () => {}

// fn handler
handler = function(e) {

  // checkbox
  var checkbox = $(this);
  
  // sure?
  if ( checkbox.attr('data-sure') || !checkbox.prop('checked') ) {
    checkbox.removeAttr('data-sure');
    return true;
  }

  //swal
 swal({
     title: 'Seleccionado',
     text: "¿Está seguro que desea seleccionarlo?",
     type: 'warning',
     showCancelButton: true,
     confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
     cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
     confirmButtonText: 'Si',
     cancelButtonText: 'No'
 }).then(function(r) {
      console.log(checkbox);
      if(r.value){
          checkbox.attr('data-sure',true);
          checkbox.click();
      }
  });
  
  // Siempre retornamos false
  return false;
}

// Anclamos el manejador al evento
$('input[name="test"]').click( handler );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.28.4/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" />
```

Espero que sea de utilidad =)

*Bienvenido a stackoverflow*